# Como salvar o valor do RadioButton e converter para String

Tags: android, radiobutton

Estou com dificuldades em encontrar um código que funcione.

Em baixo está o código que estou usando no Android Studio, esse código pega as informações do form e envia para um arquivo php para salvar no banco de dados, está funcionando bem.

O que preciso é de um código para que as informações do RadioButton sejam registradas também, não estou conseguindo registrar a String para salvar no banco de dados.

Já tentei diversos códigos mas não salva o valor do radiobutton, sempre que salva o registro ou salva números ou salva a palavra **android.widget.radio**.

A única forma que consegui salvar a informação correta é com o código:

`String opcao = rb_make.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();`

Mas se eu adicionar mais opções o programa só registra a primeira.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer para que funcione corretamente?

```
private void registerUser() {

    String nome = etNome.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String cpf = etCpf.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String telefone = etTelefone.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String endereco = etEndereco.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String cidade = etCidade.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String estado = etEstado.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String senha = etSenha.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();


    String opcao = ?????



    register(nome, email, cpf, telefone, endereco, cidade, estado, senha, opcao);

}

private void register(String nome, String email, String cpf, String telefone, String endereco, String cidade, String estado, String senha, String opcao) {

    String urlSuffix = "?nome="+nome+"&cpf="+cpf+"&senha="+senha+"&email="+email+"&telefone="+telefone+"&endereco="+endereco+"&cidade="+cidade+"&estado="+estado+"&opcao="+opcao;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
```

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18179176/4322614), estou sem nenhuma ferramenta para testar, porém me parece que atende o que você precisa, se for isso mesmo, posto como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se que você precisa ver o que está atribuindo como valor ao checkbox:

```
...
        radio= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiobu);

        // recebendo o botão selecionado
        int selectedId = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // buscando e retornando o id
        radioButao= (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        //imprimindo o texto
        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
         radioButao.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

...
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lollipop !! Adaptei o código para o meu projeto e está funcionando muito bem. Agora sim está salvando como se deve no banco de dados.  

    `// recebendo o botão selecionado
        int selectedId = selecao.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // buscando e retornando o id
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        String opcao = radioButton.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

        register(nome, email, cpf, telefone, endereco, cidade, estado, senha, opcao);`

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

Segue a solução:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText edtnome;
private RadioGroup valor;
private String opcoes = "";
private SharedPreferences save;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private int indiceSelecionado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    edtnome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    valor = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupOpcoes);
    save = getSharedPreferences("save",MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Recupera a chave nomeEdit e insere no EditText edtnome
    edtnome.setText(save.getString("nomeEdit", ""));

    //Recupera o valor do indiceSelecionado
    indiceSelecionado = save.getInt("chave_radio", 0);
    //Executa a condição abaixo para ver qual o ultimo ID que fora salvo, ou seja
    //qual o ultimo radioButton foi marcado
    if(indiceSelecionado == R.id.radioButtonEmpregado){
        valor.check(R.id.radioButtonEmpregado);
    }else if (indiceSelecionado == R.id.radioButtonDesempregado){
        valor.check(R.id.radioButtonDesempregado);
    }else if(indiceSelecionado == R.id.radioButtonNaoProcura){
        valor.check(R.id.radioButtonNaoProcura);
    }


    //Toast.makeText(this, "Id: " + indiceSelecionado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    /*
    Ao ser chamado o metodo onStop ou seja, após a aplicação parar é feito um putString
    do nome digitado pelo usuário, assim ele grava o ultimo nome digitado para que quando
    volte para a aplicação o campo Nome já esta preenchido
    */
    super.onStop();
    /*
    * A variavel indiceSelecionado pega o ID do radio button que esta marcado
    * dessa maneira é salvo ela com uma chave do tipo chave_radio, para assim
    * recuperar a mesma no método Oncreate
    * */
    indiceSelecionado = valor.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    editor = save.edit();
    editor.putString("nomeEdit", edtnome.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("chave_radio", indiceSelecionado);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.help, menu);
    return true;
}
```